# vector of char array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, char

I have the following code:

```
static unsigned char S0_gif[] = {
0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x91, 0x02,
..
};
```

It's a hex representation of a gif file. I have 500 gifs that I need to store like that so I want to use a vector to make it easier for access.

Something like:

```
vector<char[]> gifs; 
gif.push_back( {0x47, 0x49,..} );

Then in the loop:
{
MakeImage(gif[i], sizeof gif[i] );
}
```

I cannot find the right code for that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Petry

Answer (score 2):

You cant do that, because vectors store constant sized structures, and youre's are variable sized. What you can do however, is store a vector of vector :)

```
vector<vector<char> > gifs; // note the neccessary space between > >
gif.push_back( vector<char>( S0_gif, S0_gif + sizeof(S0_gif) )  );

Then in the loop:
{
MakeImage( gifs[i] );
}
```

Another idea, if they are indeed stored as static variables, is not to store the data twice:

```
vector< unsigned char * > gifs; 
vector< size_t > gifsizes; 
gifs.push_back( S0_gif );
gifsizes.push_back( sizeof(S0_gif) );

Then in the loop:
{
MakeImage( gifs[i], gifsizes[i] );
}
```

**Disclaimer :** I probably forgot some `&`'s, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Indeed I want to avoid storing data twice, so I tried your second idea but I get this MSVC2008 compilation error:
error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char (*)[819]' to 'const char *const &'
        with
        [
            _Ty=const char *
        ]
        Reason: cannot convert from 'unsigned char (*)[819]' to 'const char *const '
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are storing all 500 GIF files in a row. You cannot detect size of each without parsing its header. If your function `MakeImage` could parse GIF header you could return pointer to the next image from it.

Then the loop will look like:

```
char* img_ptr = S0_gif;
while ( img_ptr ) img_ptr = MakeImage( img_ptr );
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best solution is to generate a C/CPP file that declares a vector of images. All the rest means writing code, which is not generally recommended for a lot of initialization (my opinion).

```
unsigned char *Array[]={
S0_gif,
S1_gif,
S2_gif,
S3_gif,
...
};
```

The code for generating this can be easily written in a scripting language (bash, perl, python, etc). It should be something like this:

```
print "char *Array[]={"
for i in range(0,500)
   print "S"+i+"_gif"
print "};"
```

Is this a solution to your question?

Comment: The thing is that I need to store the images inside the executable. I have the c++ code that will turn binary files into char array.

Comment: Using the C++ code to turn binary into array you can create S0_gif, S1_gif and so on. After that you use that small script to create a C/C++ array that contains all the images represented as an unsigned char array. Isn't this what you want? [Of course after creating the CPP file you simply add it into the compilation process - and this means that it will be in the final executable]

Comment: Exactly, I need array that will contain all images represented as an unsigned char array. I tried with your first piece of code but I get this compilation error: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'unsigned char [819]' to 'char *'

Comment: my code is char *; use unsigned char * (I modified my post now)

Comment: Like that it compiles fine but the image is not decoded at all. 
When I use only MakeImage(S0_gif, sizeof S0_gif) it works fine.
<br>When I use MakeImage(Array[0], sizeof Array[0]) it doesn't.